# /usr/local/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv

Having an issue with my python install and various packages after trying to get to grips with pipenv (clearly didnt go well).

```bash
$ which Python
/usr/bin/Python

$ which python3.8
/usr/local/bin/python3.8
```

Then any command I run that isn't directly a python command throws a bad interpreter error

```bash
$ pip
zsh: /usr/local/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: no such file or directory

$ django-admin
zsh: /usr/local/bin/django-admin: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: no such file or directory
```

Not entirely sure what the cause is, so I am struggling to figure out how to resolve it. But basically any command that I run which involves a python package throws the same error

Comment: Rather than get into how either `pip` or `django-admin` was installed, this is a good point to plug using virtual environments for everything.

Comment: That was the intention of me getting to grips with pipenv (installed with homebrew). but I have now got myself into this situation. pipenv still works perfectly fine, just wanting to resolve this issue as well just incase

Comment: Start with `which -a` to find *all* the versions of Python you might have installed, and consider removing (with the original packaging tool if possible) the ones that didn't originally comes with your OS.

Comment: (It can be a mess; my computer hasn't seen a fresh OS install--macOS, in my case--in over a decade, and I've probably installed various versions of Python in that span using 3 or 4 different methods. I'm slowly converging on having just the OS-supplied installation plus a Nix install, but surprises still pop up occasionally.)

Answer (score 9):

Install `pip` this way:

First download `get-pip`:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

Then install `pip`:

```
python3 get-pip.py
```

Check `pip` installation:

```
$pip -V
pip 20.2.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Comment: Out of all methods, this worked thanks @arilwan

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve the pip issue is to link pip with a specific python version.
Say for example you want to use pip to install GeoPandas. In this example, you can link a specific python version with pip by using the command:

```
python3.8 -m pip install geopandas
```

Of course this only works if you have python3.8 installed! This should overcome the bad interpreter message without having to change any zsh or bash_profile files.

Here is a link with further explanation:

https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/